# Pass data via 'prepareForSegue' in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to pass a string from one view controller to another view controller (MoreDetailViewController)

Coming up with this error :

> unknown class MoreDetailViewController in Interface Builder file.
>   Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10f4ae308) to 'ParseStarterProject_Swift.MoreDetailViewController' (0x10d512060).
>   (lldb)

Sorry if this is obvious, but I have only recently started coding. Thank you! :)

Code :

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier == "showDetail") {
        let detailController : MoreDetailViewController  = segue.destinationViewController as! MoreDetailViewController
        detailController.receivedId = selectedId

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the `UIViewController`'s custom class as `MoreDetailViewController` in Storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
      if segue.identifier == "showDetail"
        {
            if let detailController = segue.destinationViewController as? MoreDetailViewController
            {
              detailController.receivedId = selectedId
             }
        }
```

Note: Don't forget to set viewcontroller class as MoreDetailViewController

Comment: Since the controller is designed in Interface Builder it will never be optional if the identifier and the custom class is set properly.

Comment: Better safe than sorry. Besides, let's say that you change around in the storyboard. You don't test through the entire app entirely and then you push the app to app store. Suddenly you will have a ton of crashes that provides little information rather than a button that is not working correctly. A lot better to have an app behave in the wrong way rather than crash, in my opinion.

Comment: The user experience of a crash or a malfunction – the segue is never executed –  makes actually no difference. The concept of optional bindings is not for supporting the carelessness of the developer @ClockWise

Answer (score 2):

Is your second view controller correctly set as a `MoreDetailViewController` in Interface Builder ?

You can check it easily : Open your .xib or .storyboard file, select your second view controller, and on the Identity Inspector (right panel, third tab) enter your class name.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error is simply saying that the segue destination viewcontroller is not a `MoreDetailViewController`. You should also not force unwrap it, in which case it will crash if the object is not correct.

```
if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
    if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? MoreDetailViewController {
        vc.receivedId = selectedId
    }
}
```

### Edit

Did not see previous answer which was the exact same code. Sorry about that.

Comment: As mentioned in the other  comment, the segue works either always (if the parameters are set correctly) or never which is certainly not intended. So the optional binding is meaningless in this case.

Comment: Of course it is, for the segue itself, but not to prevent a crash in case something goes wrong. I clearly stated the reason for OP's issue in the text above - as others have in the thread as well :)